# xrces item returning NULL

Tags: c++

I am parsing the xml and need to get the count of the child nodes.Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
 int getChildCount(const char* parentTag, int parentIndex, 
                                      const char* childTag)
    {
        XMLCh* temp = XMLString::transcode(parentTag);
        DOMNodeList* list = _elementRoot->getElementsByTagName(temp);
        //XMLString::release(&temp);

        //DOMNode* parent = (list->item(parentIndex));
        DOMElement* parent = dynamic_cast<DOMElement*>(list->item(parentIndex));
        DOMNodeList* childList = parent->getElementsByTagName(XMLString::transcode(childTag));
        return (int)childList->getLength();
    }
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string value;


         int length = getChildCount("Bookstore", 0, "Book");
         cout << length;
}
```

the line DOMElement* parent = dynamic_cast(list->item(parentIndex)); is failing as parent is returning NULL.

And my xml file is as below:

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="yy">
        <title lang="en">xxx</title>
        <author>hhh</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="kk">
        <title lang="en">abcd</title>
        <author>ser</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Can someone plese point what is the mistake I am doing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case sensitive - `Bookstore` is not same as `bookstore`:

```
int length = getChildCount("bookstore", 0, "Book");
```